# How To Copy/Download Azure Data Lake Storage Blob(Image file) To Azure Windows Virtual Machine Cdrive Using Managed Identity Through PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, jwt, azure-virtual-machine, azure-data-lake, azure-managed-identity

I am able to Upload File From Virtual Machine To Storage Account Container using Managed Identity Through PowerShell Scripting

I followed This Microsoft Document Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-datalake

Followed Steps:

1. I Signed into Azure Portal
2. created Managed Identity Resource
3. created one Windows VM and enabled system-assigned managed identity
4. created Azure Storage Account & Assigned Storage Blob Data Contributor role to VM under your storage account
5. Now connected to VM and run below PowerShell commands to get access token:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://storage.azure.com' -Method GET -Headers @{Metadata="true"} 
$content = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json 
$AccessToken = $content.access_token
```

Followed Below PowerShell Scripts for Uploading Files from VM TO Azure Storage Container

```
$file = "C:\Users\VMWindows0102\Desktop\test/photo.jpg" #File path
$name = (Get-Item $file).Name

$url="https://adls0102.blob.core.windows.net/container/$($name)"

$RequestHeader = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$RequestHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $AccessToken")
$RequestHeader.Add("x-ms-version", "2019-02-02")
$RequestHeader.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob")

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Put -Headers $RequestHeader -InFile $file
```

file uploaded to container successfully from VM Local Drive

**but, Now I Need Similar PowerShell Script For Download/Copy/Save Image File From Azure Storage To Virtual Machine Local Drive Using Managed Identity Please Help...**

Please Post Correct Answers Only

Comment: See step 14 : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/upload-and-download-files-from-azure-storage/ba-p/287834

Comment: I know programme way of download but, Require powershell script for download blob using manged identity.... Please read my question again

Comment: You just need to add your managed credential to the request.  You are making an HTTP connection and getting a response which is a file.  The managed connection just add additional http headers to the request.

Comment: but I need to download it through PowerShell Scripts

Answer (score 0):

Follow Steps:

1. I Sign into Azure Portal
2. create Managed Identity Resource
3. create Windows VM and enable system-assigned managed identity
4. create Azure Storage Account & Assign Storage Blob Data Contributor role to VM under your storage account
5. Now connect to VM and run below PowerShell commands to Download Blob to Virtual Machine using Managed Identity:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://storage.azure.com' -Method GET -Headers @{Metadata="true"}
$content = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$AccessToken = $content.access_token

$content.access_token
$RequestHeader = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$RequestHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $AccessToken")
$RequestHeader.Add("x-ms-version", "2019-02-02")
$RequestHeader.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob")

$url="https://adls0102.blob.core.windows.net/container/MerryChristmas.png"
$file = "C:\Users\VMWindows0102\Desktop\test\MerryChristmas.png"

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $RequestHeader -OutFile $file
```

Note: Here we don't Require extra Azure Managed Identity Resource
Thank You